# Retrieving datas from SUMO simulation started with flow using TraCI from another terminal

Tags: python, sumo

I am using Flow to start a SUMO simulation integrating deep reinforcement learning inside the process. I am also using another computer to retrieve some data from the simulation using TraCI.

The first problem is that flow does not assign the port I choose correctly.
Secondly, the other computer connects to the SUMO simulation using TraCI, but as soon as it starts it goes out and doesn't save anything. The simulation keeps going on on the other computer.

This is the code I use on the first computer to assign the port and the clients for SUMO:

```py
sim_params = SumoParams(port=45678, render=VISUALIZE_SIM_IN_SUMO, sim_step=1, num_clients=2)
```

This is the code I use on the second computer to connect with TraCi and retrieve data:

```py
# I need to set it once I start the simulation on the first computer
# since Flow does not use the port I specified at the beginning
PORT = 49745

traci.init(PORT,tc.DEFAULT_NUM_RETRIES,"second_computer.local")
traci.setOrder(2) # number can be anything as long as each client gets its number
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. I don't know why, but TraCI does not see any vehicle if it is initialised by Flow commands and for this reason the command "traci.simulation.getMinExpectedNumber()" returns 0 even if there are vehicles in the simulation.

I just changed the while condition inside the second terminal's code and everything works.